# Step by Step Tutorial for Printing from iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, printing

Are there any good step-by-step tutorials for enabling printing from within an iOS 5 application? I have an application that needs to have a basic template (looks like a ticket) that is filled with information from an object and then printed out on a local printer. I've read the basic AirPrint items on the iOS developer site but would like to find a good tutorial that puts it all together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about Apple documents on **Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS**  
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/drawingprintingios.pdf [PDF]

EDIT:
Specially look for Printing workflow or click this link to the HTML documentation online http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW14

Comment: I was about to answer with the same document, but [here's a link that takes you to the start of the printing section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW5).

Comment: Thank you to the both of you. That is a surprisingly easy to read (and implement!) document. I am using the HTML formatter to get me up & running with this and I've already printed my first document!

Answer (score 0):

Session 108 of WWDC 2011 was called "iOS Printing System" and included a deep walkthrough of all the ways to print in iOS, including a demo of creating a custom `UIPrintPageRenderer`, which is (most likely) what you'd need to do.

You can get the video, sample code, and slides from the Apple developer site: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=108

Answer (score 0):

To print any file or image from iOS device, We can use UIPrintInteractionController

```
UIPrintInteractionController *pc = [UIPrintInteractionController
                                    sharedPrintController];
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
printInfo.jobName =@"Report";

pc.printInfo = printInfo;
pc.showsPageRange = YES;
pc.printingItem = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.com/Print_for_Client_Name.pdf"]];
// You can use here image or any data type to print.


UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed,
  NSError *error) {
    if(!completed && error){
        NSLog(@"Print failed - domain: %@ error code %ld", error.domain,
              (long)error.code);
    }
};


[pc presentFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300) inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```